# How to build vue native app to apk or ios executable

Tags: android, react-native, vue.js, vue-native

I want to start developing apps using vue native. After I do all the installations how do I then compile the app to native executables.

I've found sources saying gif, but it's not understandable

I was used to the old Phonegap were we just compiled our web app to native code using Phonegap Buld.
Is there something similar to this

Comment: Check out https://vue-native.io/

Comment: Thank you @MaartenVeerman. Let me check and let you know